# How to add value to google custom search with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

I want to add a json data gotten from a database to the google custom search javascript file but i cant because jquery method of adding value to input box fails when it comes to google custom search.

any help please

here is the code:

```
(function() {
    var cx = '005172588709921972888:fsuibenly4m';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
//checks if the id is empty
     if ( $('#gsc-i-id1').is(':empty')  ) {
       console.log('search is empty');
//if is empty add this code
       $(".gsc-input").val("Dolly Duck");
     }
     else {

       console.log('search is not empty');
   };
  })();
//the above code fails because i kept on seeing "search is not empty" in log
// i tried this one and it fails again
  $("#gsc-i-id1").val("Dolly Duck");
```

`

any help please.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve the problem after checking out google's developers ref page for the cse.google.com page.
i used ?q=lady+gaga to query the url to a particular search and using ajax worked like magic.

http://localhost/ailab/searchapi.php?q=lady+gaga 
did the trick